# No sound from cam mic, until I change and change back

Tags: audio, camera, microphone

These are my OS specs:

- kernel: 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64
- bits: 64
- distribution: Cinnamon 4.6.7 Linux Mint 20 Ulyana

And this is how the system recognizes my webcam: `ARC International Camera USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo`

So, I bought a USB webcam (no jack 3.5, it transmits audio and video from the USB connection).

I want to leave it plugged, to avoid damage through multiple connections and disconnections, and also to use the mic to send WhatsApp audios on WhatsApp web and Google voice search.

But something strange happens to it.

I have chosen the webcam mic as default source. I have 3 from the camera: multichannel camera input, camera mic, and also multichannel with echo reduction (I activated that last option on mint for every source, don't remember how its been a long time)

But I think the source is no important, no matter which I choose it's the same.

So this is my problem:

On every boot, the first time I want to record audio or use the mic for any sound action it doesn't work.

But if I change manually the input from sound configuration to another source and change it back to my default source it works!

Then the mic works perfect for that session (again, no matter which input I use, I tested all and it's the same)

I attached a GIF of what I do to explain myself better.

[image]

The GIF has no sound of course, but I'm snapping my fingers next to the mic all the process for you to see that at first the bar has no movement, then when I change to another source it raises, and then when I come back to the original sources it also raises.

Also, this doesn't happen when I plug the camera with the PC already booted (which is the way I'm using it right now, because it is a waste to have it plugged if it doesn't work for WhatsApp audio and Google search). So, if I connect the camera when the PC is booted, the mic works form the start.

So I think it has something to do with not waking up the mic at boot.

Is there a way for me to do this, make my mic ready for listening when the PC is booted without having to do the attached GIF process manually every time I boot?

Or maybe the problem is elsewhere, I don't want to break anything.

Remember, I want the mic to be always ready since boot, to use it also for Google search and WhatsApp audio messages, not only for a previously appointed videocalls.